# Replace clicked row in table with a react component

Tags: reactjs

**React v15**

I'm trying to make a table without table tags. In this table I want to click in a row and make that row convert into a form with input fields in that specific row, one of which is a component and the others are simple input tags.

I can do it with vanilla JS innerHTML, but I do not want to do that because of the "Dangerously Set innerHTML" [ReactJS link](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

Is there a way to do it in react?

This is my code with a not working example [Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj2kp6jwqz). Sorry for not using the internal code editor, because I prefer the style of coding in codesandbox.

Comment: In the map function, you aren't returning anything in the if-else clauses, and thus nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main issues with you code:

1. The `render` function of `App` is not returning anything.
   Change this:

   ```
     render() {
       return data.map(row => {
         if (this.state.show) {
           <DataOutput row={row} onclick={this.handleClick} />;
         } else {
           <InputData row={row} />;
         }
       });
     }
   ```

   To this (don't forget to bind `handleClick` in the constructor and add a `key` property for each  component as we are [iterating over an array](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) ):

   ```
     render() {
       return data.map((row,index) => {
         if (this.state.show) {
           return <DataOutput key={index} row={row} onclick={this.handleClick} />;
         } else {
           return <InputData key={index} row={row} />;
         }
       });
     }
   ```
2. Inside `DataOutput` you did not use the `onclick` prop you are
   passing in:
   Change this:

   ```
   const DataOutput = props =>
     <div>
       <i className='date' style={styles}>{props.row.date}</i>
       <i className='animal' style={styles}>{props.row.animal}</i>
       <i className='name' style={styles}>{props.row.name}</i>
     </div>
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   const DataOutput = props =>
     <div onClick={props.onclick}>
       <i className='date' style={styles}>{props.row.date}</i>
       <i className='animal' style={styles}>{props.row.animal}</i>
       <i className='name' style={styles}>{props.row.name}</i>
     </div>
   ```

**Note** that you are using lowercase `onclick` and not camel-case `onClick`.

**EDIT**:
As a followup to your comment:

> i'm getting an error from Datepicker, its not a react error, but
>   still can't get the final result! The error is: date.clone is not a
>   function

That because `react-datePicker` expect a [moment](https://momentjs.com/) object (it uses its `clone` method).  You didn't include it in your solution and you didn't pass a `moment` object, but instead you passed a simple string as a `date`.

It should look something like this:

```
this.state = {startDate: moment(this.props.row.date, "DD/MM/YYYY")}
```

**Edit #2**
As a followup to your other comment:

> I get the form element in every row, when I want in only the row that
>   I click. Is there a way?

You would need to keep track of rows that were clicked, you could use an object as a simple lookup table, maybe each row will get an `id` and this will be the `key` in the lookup table and the value would be `true` or `false` (clicked or not).

I think it's time for you to think about creating another component `Row` that will be responsible on how to render the row, it will expect an `isEditable` Boolean and will render `InputData` or `DataOutput` respectively.
It will also expect a `rowId` as a prop and a `onClick` handler which it will pass up to the parent the relevant rowId that was clicked.
This way the parent can store this `rowId` in the lookup table (inside the `state`) and will re-render the table but this time the `Row` will be "Editable".

The `Row` component:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    const { handleClick, rowId } = this.props;
    handleClick(rowId);
  };

  render() {
    const { isEditable, row } = this.props;
    const ComponentToRender = isEditable ? (
      <InputData row={row} />
    ) : (
      <DataOutput row={row} onclick={this.onClick} />
    );

    return ComponentToRender;
  }
}
```

The new code for `App`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rows: {}
    };
  }

  handleClick(rowId) {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      rows: {
        ...rows,
        [rowId]: true
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    return data.map((row, index) => {
      const isEditable = rows[index];
      return (
        <Row
          row={row}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          rowId={index}
          isEditable={isEditable}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: He's also going to need a "key" property for the DataOutput and InputData calls?  Or is that just React 16?

Comment: a "key" is defiantly needed in this case as we are mapping over an array.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer as correct, but i'm getting an error from Datepicker, its not a react error, but still can't get the final result! The error is: date.clone is not a function, the code is: https://codesandbox.io/s/oj2kp6jwqz

Comment: seems like you forgot to import moment.js?

Comment: I required it, and got the same error. If I remove the component, I get the form element in every row, when I want in only the row that I click. Is there a way?

Comment: You need to use moment, not only require it. You need to pass a moment object but instead you are passing a string which of course doesnt have the `.clone` function. See my edit answer on how you should use it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! But It changes all rows, I only want the one I click in... Is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159775/discussion-between-luis-alves-and-sag1v).